# Add a css class to graphics in tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

So I have this

`\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{./src/images/screenshot--superman.png}`

And using `make4ht` (`tex4ht`) it generates the following markup (I'm pasting it as outputed):

```
<p>   <img 
src="./src/images/screenshot--superman.png" alt="PIC"  
 />
<a 
 id="x1-2038r1"></a>
</p>
```

But It would be pretty awesome to add classes to that image using LaTeX with some kind of hack.

`<img class="my-class" src="./src/images/screenshot--superman.png" alt="PIC" />`

Is that doable through LaTeX itself, or should I set up some `tex4ht` hooks to add an enclosing `<div class="my-class"> <img> </div>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\Configure{IMG}`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Configure{IMG}{\HCode{<img class="my-class" src="}}{\HCode{" alt="}}{}{\HCode{"}}{\HCode{ />}}

\EndPreamble
```

This produces

```html
<p class="noindent" ><img class="my-class" src="./src/images/screenshot--superman.png" alt="PIC" /> </p>
```

if you want to preserve the image dimensions, you need to create `.xbb` file, which holds image dimensions. It can be created using `ebb command:

```
ebb -x src/img/*.png
```

the dimensions are now calculated:

```html
<p class="noindent" ><img class="my-class" src="./src/images/screenshot--superman.png" alt="PIC"        
width="172.5pt" height="56.58652pt"  /> </p>
```

Comment: Had to be you @michal.h21, you're amazing, thanks

Comment: @Claudiordgz you are welcome :)

Comment: @michal.h21 I'd like to get rid of the `<p>` tag wrapping `<img>`, but I can't see how to modify `\Configure{IMG}` in order to obtain that. Let me know if you think I should ask a new question on this regard.

Comment: @michal.h21 Update: adding `\IgnorePar\EndP`at beginning of 1st argument of `\Configure{IMG}` I managed to make tex4ht close the `<p>` tag before the `<img...>` tag, but now I have an annoying empty HTML paragraph `<p></p>` before `<img...>`.

Comment: @mmj this might be worth it's own question :)

Comment: @michal.h21 I posted a specific question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/328849/28685