# tex4ht: customize \includegraphics conversion to HTML

Tags: graphics, tex4ht, html

Compiling (Tex Live 2016 under Windows 10) the following LaTeX MWE (`mwe1.tex`)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Look at picture

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{myimage.png}
\end{figure}

Nice, isn't it?

\end{document}
```

with (an image named `myimage.png` must be provided)

```
htlatex "mwe1.tex" "xhtml,charset=utf-8,fn-in" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

`tex4ht` generates

```
...
<body 
>
<!--l. 7--><p class="noindent" >Look at picture
</p>
   <hr class="figure" /><div class="figure" 
>



<!--l. 10--><p class="noindent" ><img 
src="myimage.png" alt="PIC"  
 />

</p>
   </div><hr class="endfigure" />
<!--l. 13--><p class="indent" >   Nice, isn’t it?
</p>

</body>
...
```

I'd like to customize this HTML output by getting rid of the unneeded `<p>` tag wrapping `<img...>` and, if possible, by giving some meaningful value to the `alt` attribute.

I know that image is enclosed in a paragraph in LaTeX source, but I don't need it in HTML source (especially if it is placed around `<img>` instead of around `<div class="figure">...</div>`).

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290414/28685) deals with the subject but I wasn't able to find a solution by modifying it.

Can I achieve this result by a custom configuration file or by some other means?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please make a `mwe`? This might depend on surrounding code.

Comment: @michal.h21 MWE added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to configure the `figure` environment and disable paragraphs inside it (I hope that you don't use paragraphs inside `\caption` command):

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\begin{document}
\ConfigureEnv{figure}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="figure">}\HtmlParOff}
{\HCode{</div>}\HtmlParOn\par}{}{}
\EndPreamble
```

`\HtmlParOff` ... `\HtmlParOn` disables the paragraphs.

Regarding the image `alt` attribute, we can add new option for the `\includegraphics` command. We must create new package, say `altgraphicx.sty`, which will provide default definition of this key:

```
\ProvidesPackage{altgraphicx}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\define@key{Gin}{alt}{}

\endinput
```

Then, we must provide `tex4ht` configuration for this package, `altgraphicx.4ht`:

```
\define@key{Gin}{alt}{\Configure{GraphicsAlt}{#1}}
\endinput
```

`\Configure{GraphicsAlt}` is used to store contents of the `alt` attribute.

You can now use `\includegraphics` in the following way:

```
\includegraphics[width=20cm,alt={Image description}]{myimage.png}
```

Generated code:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<!--l. 6--><p class="noindent" >Look at picture
</p>
   <div class="figure">

   <a 
 id="x1-21"></a><hr class="float" /><div class="float" 
>


<img 
src="myimage.png" alt="Image description"   
width="569.05511pt" height="186.6778pt"  />
 <div class="caption" 
><span class="id">Figure 1: </span><span  
class="content">hello my image</span></div><!--tex4ht:label?: x1-21 -->

   </div><hr class="endfloat" />
   </div>
<!--l. 14--><p class="indent" >   Nice, isn&#x2019;t it?
</p>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. Since I already have a custom `tex4ht` configuration of `figure` environment, I just added `\HtmlParOff` and `\HtmlParOn` to my configuration and it worked.

Comment: @mmj see the updated answer

Comment: The solution that allows specification of `alt` attribute works wonderfully, you are a wizard!