# htlatex: img with alt tag and custom class

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, accessibility

This question is something of a follow-up to [tex4ht: customize \includegraphics conversion to HTML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328849/tex4ht-customize-includegraphics-conversion-to-html) and also to [When generating html, how do you specify image size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64919/when-generating-html-how-do-you-specify-image-size)

### background

In my `.tex` file I specify images to be included as follows:

```
\includegraphics[alt={alt tags, information}]{example-image-a}
```

and have the`img` element wrapped in its own container:

```
<div class="figure"><!--l. 7-->
<p class="noindent"></p>
<div class="my-box"><img src="mwe0x.png" alt="PIC" class=
"my-class" /></div>
<!--l. 8-->
<p class="indent"></p>
</div>
```

I use the following `cmh.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{html5}
\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{alt}{}
\Configure{GraphicsAlt}{my alt text}
\Configure{graphics}
  {\HCode{<div class="my-box">}%
   \Picture+[PIC]{ class="my-class"}}
  {\EndPicture \HCode{</div>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

and produce the html output above using the call:

```
make4ht -u -f html5 -c cmh.cfg mwe.tex
```

### goal

I'd like to have the `ALT` tag updated from the `includegraphics` call.

I've tried the following modification to `cmh.cfg`

```
\Picture+[\a:GraphicsAlt]{ class="my-class"}}
```

but this results in

> Missing $ inserted

### the question

How can I change my `cmh.cfg` file so that the `img` element receives custom `alt` tags and my custom class?

### mwe.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

here is some text
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[alt={descriptions,info}]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### `cmh.cfg`

```
\Preamble{html5}
\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{alt}{}
\Configure{GraphicsAlt}{my alt text}
\Configure{graphics}
  {\HCode{<div class="my-box">}%
   \Picture+[PIC]{ class="my-class"}}
  {\EndPicture \HCode{</div>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

### call

```
make4ht -u -f html5 -c cmh.cfg mwe.tex
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.jpg,.svg}
\define@key{Gin}{alt}{\Configure{GraphicsAlt}{#1}}
\def\mygraphics{{\Configure{Needs}{File: \Gin@base\Gin@ext}\Needs{}}%
   \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="my-box">}\Picture[\csname a:GraphicsAlt\endcsname]{{\Gin@base\Gin@ext} \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname class="my-class" 
}\HCode{</div>}\ShowPar}
\Configure{graphics*}
   {png}
   {\mygraphics}
\Configure{graphics*}
   {jpg}
   {\mygraphics}
\Configure{graphics*}
   {jpeg}
   {\mygraphics}
\Configure{graphics*}
   {svg}
   {\mygraphics}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

The `\DeclareGraphicsExtension` is used to declare graphics filetypes supported in HTML. The `\mygraphics` macro contains common code inserted for graphics, especially dimensions, alt and class. It is then used in configurations for supported graphics types, so we can save some repetition. The alt text is declared by `\define@key{Gin}{alt}{\Configure{GraphicsAlt}{#1}}`.

You also need to copy the `example-image-a.png` file to the current directory and save its dimensions using `ebb -x example-image-a.png` command.

The result:

```xml
<!--l. 8--><p class="noindent" >here is some text </p><figure class="figure"> 



<!--l. 10--><p class="noindent" ></p><div class="my-box"><img 
src="example-image-a.png" alt="descriptions,info"  
width="401" height="301" class="my-class"  /></div>

   </figure>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. As always, very helpful and insightful