# alt text for images in ODT files produced by make4ht

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht, accessibility

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482176/110494) describes a way to have make4ht take a LaTeX source file and produce an HTML file which includes alt text for images.  Is it possible to use make4ht to produce ODT files containing alt text from LaTeX source files? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX4ht and the `graphicx` package now support alt texts out of the box, just use the `alt` keyval property:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[alt={my alt text}]{example-image.png}

\includegraphics[]{example-image.png}
\end{document}
```

It is not supported in the ODT format yet, but you can add support using the following config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\makeatletter
\NewConfigure{GraphicsAlt}{1}
\Configure{IMG}
  {% parse the image extension, will be used later
\expandafter\filename@parse\expandafter{\PictureFile}%
\ifx\a:GraphicsAlt\relax%
\Configure{GraphicsAlt}{ALT}%
\fi%
\ifx\Gin@base\@undefined
\let\graphics:filename\PictureFile
\else
\def\graphics:filename{\Gin@base\Gin@ext}
\fi
% \ht:special{t4ht>\PictureFile.4og}%
\ht:special{t4ht>\graphics:filename.4og}%
\ht:special{t4ht*>}%
% \ht:special{t4ht<\PictureFile.4og}%
\ht:special{t4ht<\graphics:filename.4og}%
\OOmanifest{<manifest:file-entry
   manifest:full-path="Pictures/\PictureFile" manifest:media-type="\get:image:mime:type\filename@ext"/>\Hnewline
}%
%
   \ht:special{t4ht=<draw:frame
      draw:name="\PictureFile"
      text:anchor-type="as-char"  % "paragraph"
        % insert image dimension only if they really exist
        \ifx\noBoundingBox\UnDefined
         \ifx\Gin@req@width\undefined\else
         \ifdim\Gin@req@width>0pt
         \string svg:width="\the\Gin@req@width"
          svg:height="\the\Gin@req@height"
        \fi\fi\fi
      draw:z-index="0"
    >%
      <draw:image\Hnewline
         xlink:href="Pictures/}}
  {\ht:special{t4ht=" \Hnewline
         xlink:type="simple"
        xlink:show="embed"
        xlink:actuate="onLoad"
        /><!--draw:name="}}
  {" }
  {\ht:special{t4ht=" }}
  {\ht:special{t4ht=--><svg:title>\a:GraphicsAlt</svg:title></draw:frame>}}
\catcode`\:=12
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It reuses the image drawing code from TeX4ht sources, with just few extra lines:

```
\ifx\a:GraphicsAlt\relax%
\Configure{GraphicsAlt}{ALT}%
\fi%
```

The `alt` key defines the `\a:GraphicsAlt` macro. If the key isn't used in th e `\includegraphics` command, it defined a default value of `ALT`.

The alt text itself is included by this code:

```
  {\ht:special{t4ht=--><svg:title>\a:GraphicsAlt</svg:title></draw:frame>}}
```

Here are the image properties in LO, with alt text set:

[image]